# How to create a ScriptBundle from dynamically generated content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, scriptbundle

I have a big Javascript file generated dynamically from a method in a Controller.

```
public ActionResult GetEditingContext()
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...);

    return JavaScript(json);
}
```

The javascript is almost always the same, but the user can change settings in the admin panel and the javascript should be updated. 
I thought that a ScriptBundle would be perfect to handle that. It would automatically check if the content has changed and update the url for the script.

The problem is that I don't know how to include a URL in a bundle.

I tried this :

```
bundles.Add(new TsBundle("~/bundles/editContext").Include(
            "~/Invoice/GetEditingContext"));
```

But the generated script bundle is empty, and has no hash. If I remove the ~ I get an exeption (Only application relative URLs (~/url) are allowed.)

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650541/how-to-add-bundles-with-dynamic-content-to-asp-net-web-optimization